# How to close a compact UIDatePicker popup when choosing a date?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` whose `Preferred Style` is set to `Compact` and I want to close its calendar popup once the user changes the date. I tried to look for an answer but I can't find anyone talking about it.

Comment: If so user may need to open the picker multi times if he want to set the date and time at same time . Actually , we could close the popup by tapping the  rest area of the screen .

Comment: I already know this but is there a way to force close the pop-up once the user changes the date?

Comment: Just fyi - this is also addressed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109078/close-uidatepicker-after-selection-when-style-is-compact?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to implement it you need to create a custom Picker .

#### in UIViewController

```
    UITextField textField;
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();


        textField = new UITextField(new CGRect(10, 100, 200, 80));

        textField.TextColor = UIColor.Red;
        textField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray; // you could set the style as you want 
       // textField.Delegate = new MyPickerDelegate();

        UIDatePicker datePicker = new UIDatePicker();
        datePicker.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        datePicker.ValueChanged += DatePicker_ValueChanged;
        
        if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(14,0))
        {
            datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Inline;
        }

        else
        {
            datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;
        }

        textField.InputView = datePicker;

        View.AddSubview(textField);
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    private void DatePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = sender as UIDatePicker;

        var date = picker.Date;

        var dateFormatter =new NSDateFormatter();

        dateFormatter.DateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm";

        var dateString = dateFormatter.ToString(date);
        textField.Text = dateString;
        textField.ResignFirstResponder();


    }


    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        textField.ResignFirstResponder();

    }
```