# Close UIDatePicker after selection when style is .compact

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker, xcode-storyboard

Storyboard application using Swift.

How can I close the calendar (presented for date selection when the UIDatePicker style is .compact) after a user selects a date? Currently, the user is required to tap outside the calendar for it to close. I want it to close automatically after a user has selected a date.

I've tried resigning first responder of the UIDatePicker, ending editing in the table view controller once a notification is received that a date changed, reading another response ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142873/how-to-close-a-compact-uidatepicker-popup-when-choosing-a-date)) and so far nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For now, you can do:

```
presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i.e.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
}

@objc private func dateChanged() {
    presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**But note that this will potentially break in future iOS versions** as this relies on the implementation detail that `compact` date pickers *presents a view controller* to show the calendar. If you print out the type of the presented VC, you'll see `_UIDatePickerIOSCompactViewController`. The leading `_` suggests that this is an implementation detail.

All that is documented about `compact` is:

> A style indicating that the date picker displays as a label that when tapped displays a calendar-style editor.

So in future versions of iOS, they could instead change the implementation to not present a new view controller, and this could very well break, and you'll have to find another way then. I see no documented way of doing this right now.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and solves my problem. My specific implementation is a UITableViewController, each row in the table has a date picker, so I added the target for each datepicker in cellForRowAt. Works great. Hope it doesn't break anytime soon!

Comment: It is ridiculous that we need this workaround. The UIDatePicker API is embarrassing.

Comment: Still works great for iOS 16.