# Dismissing a UIDatePicker By AddTarget function also dismiss while selecting year

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to dismiss a datePicker during selection of date by addTarget function. After when I select year it dismiss before I select date and when I select the date first I cannot select year. what I actually want is, during selection of year it shouldn't dismiss. It should dismiss when I select date. Is there any possible solution for this with using UIdatePicker ?

This is my code

```
let datePicker : UIDatePicker = {
    let date = UIDatePicker()
    date.datePickerMode = .date
    date.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
    date.tintColor =  UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 176/255, blue: 184/255, alpha: 1)
    return date
}()
func config() {
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectButtonAction), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
}
@objc func selectButtonAction() {
    // code logic ...

    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I believe you can check what the user is selecting (month-year or the calendar) by traversing through the view hierarchy. But this is a *very very* fragile approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to dismiss the current VC when the user selects a date in this state:

[image]

But you don't want to do anything if the user changes the month/year in this state:

[image]

There is no officially supported way to do this - you are not supposed to use a `UIDatePicker` in this way.

I suggest adding an "OK" button or something to that effect, to let the user confirm that they have selected a date. Think about the case of a user mis-taps on the calendar, and end up accidentally dismissing the whole VC. That's quite frustrating if you ask me.

If you really want a behaviour like this, I would suggest making your own date selector.

That said, the month-year selector is, after all, a `UIView`, and can be found in the view hierarchy. After some reverse-engineering, that view is called `_UICalendarMonthYearSelector`, as of iOS 16.

So theoretically, in `selectButtonAction`, you can try to find this view in the hierarchy, and do not `dismiss` if you found it. This is **heavily** subject to changes in the implementation of `UIDatePicker` and `UICalendarView`. This will probably break in the future.

```
func findViewInViewHierarchy(root: UIView, target: AnyClass) -> UIView? {
    if root.isKind(of: target) {
        return root
    }
    for subview in root.subviews {
        if let found = findViewInViewHierarchy(root: subview, target: target) {
            return found
        }
    }
    return nil
}

@objc func selectButtonAction() {
    // for .compact style date pickers, use presentedViewController.view! as the root
    // for .inline style date pickers, use the date picker itself as the root
    let monthYearSelector = findViewInViewHierarchy(root: presentedViewController.view!, target: NSClassFromString("_UICalendarMonthYearSelector")!)
    if calendar == nil {
        // dismiss...
    }
}
```

If you actually wanted to dismiss the pop up that a `.compact` style date picker shows, rather than `self`, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67109486/5133585).

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly as I expected